# Is There A Way To Sign In With LinkedIn Without Using the Webview on iOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I'd like to implement sign in functionality to my iOS app with LinkedIn. So far all the examples I have seen that are using OAuth with LinkedIn use a pop up webview. But is it possible to create a custom native view that uses the LinkedIn API to sign in?

Thanks 
James

Comment: You don't have to use a UIWebView - you can catch the responses yourself and render what you wish, it's just more work for no reason!

Comment: LinkedIn recently announced the general availability of a native Android Mobile SDK.  If you check out https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq under the "Mobile SDK" section, the native iOS version is on the way.

Comment: That sounds perfect - do you know when it will be available? Any chance of beta access?

Comment: How I use with webview, in the API for iOS I just find to login with LinkedIn app, they may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk . However, the user will have to have the app install (or install it after a popup shows up). 
The scenario that I have right now, checks if the user has the LinkedIn app installed, if he doesn't, it will open up as a webview.